# Should I use `coated papers` or `Coated Paper`, or either way is fine?

Tags: proper-nouns

> Our company mainly sells printing materials and printing papers, coated papers, offset papers, book papers, light-weight papers, as well as white kraft paper bags, sticky labels, cash register papers, and notebooks.

Should I use `coated papers` or `Coated Paper`, or either way is fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on whether or not the word is a *proper noun*. In your case, it seems that "coated" is just a type of paper. If "Coated Paper" is an official (may be trademarked) name of the product, it should be capitalized as "Coated Paper". However, if it's just another type of paper and the name is that of a material (steel, stainless steel, paper, etc), don't capitalize it.

tl;dr: You probably shouldn't capitalize "coated paper"